# rename text before numerical value using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, rename, batch-rename

I have a list of files that need to be renamed, the original values are on the left the new values are on the right as follows:

```
B000R825I0_1.jpg    test_1.jpg
B000R825I0_2.jpg    test_2.jpg
```

I am new to batch files but I have attempted the following:

```
ren B000R825I0*.jpg test*.jpg
```

The renamed files are now incorrectly showing as the values below:

```
testR825I0_1.jpg
testR825I0_2.jpg
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, please can someone assist me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to rename files with script from the command like but i do use a really good Windows File Renamer. The basic version is free. I have found a way to do everything i have wanted to do (so far). Hope this helps. Link to website below:
http://www.sherrodcomputers.com/products_filerenamer.cfm

Comment: thank you for your response, looks really good but I'm really keen on getting this batch script to work, I'm hoping i'm not too far off in regards to getting it working fully